# Как добавлять значения динамических полей в бд

Tags: php, mysql

есть такая форма которая добавляет поля при нажатии на кнопку. Как сделать что бы значения этих полей добавлялось в базу данных? Может направите на какие то статьи? заранее спасибо

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var d = document;
  var last_id = 0;
  function add_value_f() {

      var tbody = d.getElementById('v_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

      var row = d.createElement("tr");
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  
      var td1 = d.createElement("td");
      var td2 = d.createElement("td");
    var td3 = d.createElement("td");
    var td4 = d.createElement("td");
    var td5 = d.createElement("td");
  
      row.appendChild(td1);
      row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    row.appendChild(td4);
    row.appendChild(td5);
    
    last_id = last_id + 1;
    
    row.setAttribute('id', 'item'+last_id);

      td1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="xml_id['+last_id+']">';
      td2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="values['+last_id+']">';
    td3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="val_sort['+last_id+']" value="500">';
    td4.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" name="default" value="'+last_id+'">';
    td5.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="del_input('+last_id+')">удалить</a>';
    
  }
  
  function del_input(id){
    var inp = document.getElementById("item"+id);
    inp.remove();
  }
  </script>

<form method="post">
  <table border="1" id="v_table">
  
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>xml_id</th>
    <th>значение</th>
    <th>сорт.</th>
    <th>по умол.<input type="radio" name="default" value="none" checked=""></th>
    <th>удалить</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr id="item0">
    <td><input type="text" name="xml_id[0]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="values[0]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="val_sort[0]" value="500"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="default" value="0"></td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
  <input type="button" onclick="add_value_f()" value="Добавить поле">
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Сохранить">
  </form>
```

Comment: поля формы не добавляют в базу данных. Форма находится на компьютере у посетителя сайта, а база данных на сервере. И формы можно отправить данные только в РНР. А уже из РНР можно записать в БД. И это будут две разные, никак не связанные между собой задачи

Comment: Знаете ли вы какую нидубь статью которая подходит под мою задачу?

Comment: Только учебник по РНР. Я уже писал выше, что это не "задача". Это несколько задач. Задача это "в РНР з массива записать несколько строк в БД". или "отправить на сервер массив данных яваскриптом".

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо большое

Comment: Это настолько разные здачи что у них даже теги будут разные. у первого это php и mysql, а у второго - html и яваскрипт. Вы бы хоть сказали, на каком этапе у вас проблемы. На этапе отправки на сервер?

Comment: Да, на этапе отправки на сервер. Форма которая создает поля уже есть. Мне нужно что бы все новые поля добавлялись на сервер, что бы потом я смог вывести эти данные в админку и что бы эти значения могли редактироваться со стороны клиента и со стороны администратора сайта. Просто я сейчас делаю личный кабинет на opencart, есть страница редактирования информации пользователя и есть стандартные поля (имя, фамилия). Нужно добавить динамические поля

Comment: стоп. сервер - это **веб**-сервер. Давайте я повторю. Данные из формы **не пишутся в БД**. У формы нет никакой связи с БД. Из формы любые данные можно отправить только в РНР. про базу данных надо сначала забыть. У вас в **РНР** получается принять эти данные?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как это получить данные в php. Просто сделал форму в twig есть уже созданные поля от opencart, хочу просто сделать так что бы эти поля дублировались и что бы эти данные так же сохранялись в бд

Comment: я думаю вам надо обратиться к руководству по opencart. потому что стандартные сведения по РНР и mysql тут не помогут

Comment: Я еще поищу информацию. Спасибо

Comment: @Ипатьев, получилось. Теперь еще один вопрос. ``` <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","customdynamycbutton");

$data = $_POST['text_field'];
$data = implode(",",$data);

$query = "INSERT INTO `teachers`(`name`) VALUES ('$data')";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)) {
    echo "Success: Все круто";
} else {
    echo "Error: не загрузилось";
}

$db = null;
?> ```. Как мне теперь сделать что бы поля можно было редактировать со стороны клиента? После обновления поля обнуляются, в базе данных все сохраняется. Мне теперь нужно редактировать поля и значения в базе данных

Comment: сделать форму для редактирования